# How to pass parametr from jenkins inside docker

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

I try to pass any parameter into the test project, but nothing works.

- First of all, need to say - the Jenkins is deployed on the AWS server from the docker container - maybe this is the reason why my tryings weren't successful.

So last, what I used was a `parameterized` build:

[image]

I displayed `filename` parameter with the `Shell executor`, so all settings are correct:

[image]

But I can't get this parameter in the code:

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("filename"));`//empty string or null in the result

---

**So, how is it possible to pass parameters from Jenkins in my case?**

---

**Additional info**

My project is the test project, written on the Java, builder is Gradle.

Code, where I try to get parameter is simple Test:

```
@Test
public void test1(){
    Syste.out.println(System.getProperty("filename"));
}
```

Comment: Is this a freestyle job or a pipeline?  You should be able to reference the parameter in Groovy as follows println "The filename value is `${param.filename}`"

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli 1: No pipeline using. 2: I got an exception when I added groovy script: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: param for class: Script1`

Comment: So what project type is this?  Also what "code" are you talking about?  Post the code and where you want to inject the param

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli this is a Java test project.

Comment: This doesnt answer my question unfortunately.  Are you saying you want to execute a Java application using a Jenkins Freestyle project, and you want to pass the parameter into the Java application?  If so please post the Jenkins code you have thus far.  We need to understand the question before we can assist

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli I haven't Jenkins code and did not write Jenkins code newer in my life. I just use Jenkins for run/job/test execution. Gradle task executed from Jenkins-Build, by Gradle plugin. This plugin executes the command `gradle testName`.  I also try to pass parameters with this command: `gradle testName -Dfilename=name`, but this solution also does not work, however, it works from local properly.

Comment: have you tried `gradle testName -Dfilename=$filename`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that I used the wrong function for parameter getting. Instead `getProperty()` needs to use `getenv()`:

`System.getenv("filename");`